# Why do the "using" directive and "using" statement use the same keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, statement

The [`using` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) gives us access to types without using their fully-qualified names:

```
using MyNamespace.Foo.Bar;
```

The [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) acts as syntactic sugar for `try`/`finally` blocks which ensure that objects are disposed of properly:

```
using(var x = new MyDisposableClass()) { ... }
```

These two situations seem to have nothing to do with one another. Why do they use the same keyword?

I doubt anyone would ever get the two cases confused, but it seems odd to not create a new word for a new piece of functionality.

---

As an aside, I've read about the double use of `class` in C++ as well (one for declaring classes, one for defining template parameters), but the second case eventually got its own keyword, `typename`, which makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in that both uses of `using` are unrelated.

However, there are several good reasons to use `using` in both cases.

- The `using` statement was created for .NET 1.0 and makes semantic sense ("I'm using this namespace in the following code")
- In both cases, `using` makes semantic sense.  In plain English, you are `using` a namespace or you are `using` the declared disposable object.
- By overloading the `using` keyword, the language designers did not have to create another reserved word in the language.  This helps keep the language cleaner.

It is possible that given their time again, the language designers may have chosen to use `import` for namespace declarations to disambiguate the two choices (`using` a disposable object came in a later version of .NET).  We will never know and it really isn't important since it's extremely clear which of the two meanings you're using due to the context.

Having said all of that, don't go and litter your code with `using MyNamespace.DisposableObject = DisposableObject;` namespace aliases everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand on what you mean by "helps keep the language cleaner"? In my mind, overloading the keyword makes the language less clean. I'd think it would be cleaner to make a new keyword and use separate keywords for separate functionalities.

Comment: Keywords cannot be used as identifiers. Introducing a new keyword breaks each and every program that happens to use that keyword as an identifier. You can only introduce a keyword in a backwards-compatible manner if you have access to every line of source code ever written in the entire history of C♯, including proprietary source code, secret source code, military source code, and so on.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, Not completely true. C# has a whole bunch of contextual keywords that were added in ways that meant existing identifiers with that name don't conflict with the code. `var` being the classic example where an in-scope type named `var` takes precedence over the keyword.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Or the alternative is to make the language version of the compiler selectable (like `g++ --std=c++11`, or to allow source files to specify a dialect (as in Haskell (?), Racket, Perl, even Python). A language can also be designed in a way that keywords never clash syntactically with possible identifiers, without reserving some identifiers (though that might be difficult for your run-off-the-mill language implementation using a LALR parser with a lexer in front).

Comment: @DavidArno yes, you can add a contextual keyword, but it is only backwards compatible if an identifier in that position would have previously  been ungrammatical.

Comment: @Caleth, Incorrect. C#'s `var` keyword being an example of a keyword introduced in a context where an identifier was already grammatically correct.

Comment: I disagree the designers might just as well have been using `import`. Java uses `import`, and given C# otherwise is very close to Java syntax, I think it was a very deliberate decision to not use `import`. Possibly because it would be misleading since it doesn't actually import anything.

Comment: @DavidArno have you read the rules for how var is treated? You can get semantic changes in faraway code by introducing / removing names from a scope.

Comment: @Caleth, yes I have. Have you? Your statement "*you can add a contextual keyword, but it is only backwards compatible if an identifier in that position would have previously been ungrammatical*" is incorrect for `var`. This is a fact and isn't up for discussion. I'm therefore confused as to the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @DavidArno I'm making the point that the case of `var` is not backwards compatible, because of the possibility of a type named var. That there have to be rules for how to disambiguate it, which are different from the general rule of "ambiguous type identifiers are a compile time error" is my point

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I assumed that since I could make identifiers named `var`, I could do the same with `using`, but I see this isn't the case.

Comment: @eigenchris you can always preceden keword with a @ to use it as an identifier like `@using`

Comment: @JacquesB  when they repurposed their Java compiler for Cool, I mean C#, I suppose they had to rename a few things to help differentiate the languages further. Having said that, I agree about the semantics of "import" given that nothing is actually imported. The keyword "reference" or "references" or "reflib" or even just "ref" might have worked just as well in that context, although I've never been bothered by the overloaded use of "using," personally.

Answer (score 4):

Language designers generally try to limit the number of keywords. When a keyword is reserved it cannot be used as an identifier in user code, which is annoying if it is just the word you need. It is also a hindrance when porting code from other languages - and Microsoft wanted people to port code from Java to C#. C# does have more keywords than Java, but each new keyword would make it more difficult. Furthermore, the .net languages is designed to interact with API's written in different languages which may not have the same keywords, which leads to annoyances if a public member is also a keyword.

The two uses of `using` are unambiguous, since they appear in positions in the syntax, an "using" is an appropriate term in both cases. So it makes sense to reuse the same keyword. You will note other examples of re-use of keywords, for example:

- `new` in generic constraints
- `in` in `foreach` and in variant type parameters
- `default`as a clause in `switch` and as an operator (`default(T)`).